# python gremlin connection timeout issue

Tags: python, graph, connection, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Getting gremlin driver timeout issue as below. We have increased the throughput and tried but still in vein.

```
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "Integrated_Algorithm_PD_MChart_V0.2.py", line 120, in <module>
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]     productDevelopment_cs_response = execute_traversals(client)
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "Integrated_Algorithm_PD_MChart_V0.2.py", line 77, in execute_traversals
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]     for result in callback.result():
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python364x86\python364x86\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\resultset.py", line 61, in __next__
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]     result = self.one()
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python364x86\python364x86\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\resultset.py", line 83, in one
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]     return self.done.result()
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "E:\A\_work\79\b\source_packages\pythonx86.3.6.4\tools\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "E:\A\_work\79\b\source_packages\pythonx86.3.6.4\tools\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "E:\A\_work\79\b\source_packages\pythonx86.3.6.4\tools\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 56, in run
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python364x86\python364x86\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\connection.py", line 83, in _receive
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]     status_code = self._protocol.data_received(data, self._results)
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]   File "D:\home\python364x86\python364x86\lib\site-packages\gremlin_python\driver\protocol.py", line 81, in data_received
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ]     'message': 'Server disconnected - please try to reconnect', 'attributes': {}})
[12/05/2019 06:50:33 > 1376bf: ERR ] gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: Server disconnected - please try to reconnect
[12/05/2019 06:50:34 > 1376bf: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[12/05/2019 06:50:34 > 1376bf: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

Comment: I think that you need to explain more about what you're doing. what is the nature of your Gremlin traversal that is leading to the timeout?

Comment: The gremline driver timeout happens after 3 minutes. When the records are less say less than 1000 its getting succeeded with in 3 minutes.However if records are more say 10k and if it takes more than 3 minutes it fails. I have checked configurations available for gremlin-python and tried to change the properties. But no luck. Below is the client properties we use  client = client.Client("",'g', 
    username="", 
    password="",
    message_serializer=serializer.GraphSONSerializersV2d0())
Also tried to change the gremlin python properties