# Gremlin Python - "Server disconnected - please try to reconnect" error

Tags: python, gremlin, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I have a Flask web app in which I want to keep a persistent connection to an AWS Neptune graph database. This connection is established as follows:

```
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

neptune_endpt = 'db-instance-x.xxxxxxxxxx.xx-xxxxx-x.neptune.amazonaws.com'
remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection(f'wss://{neptune_endpt}:8182/gremlin','g')
self.g = traversal().withRemote(remoteConn)
```

The issue I'm facing is that the connection automatically drops off if left idle, and I cannot find a way to detect if the connection has dropped off (so that I can reconnect by using the code snippet above).

I have seen this similar issue: [Gremlin server withRemote connection closed - how to reconnect automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386299/gremlin-server-withremote-connection-closed-how-to-reconnect-automatically) however that question has no solution as well. This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191457/python-gremlin-connection-timeout-issue) has no answer either.

I've tried the following two solutions (both of which did not work):

1. I setup my webapp behind four Gunicorn workers with a timeout of a 100 seconds, hoping that worker restarts would take care of Gremlin timeouts.
2. I tried catching exceptions to detect if the connection has dropped off. Every time I use `self.g` to do some traversal on my graph, I try to "refresh" the connection, by which I mean this:

```
def _refresh_neptune(self):
    try:
        self.g = traversal().withRemote(self.conn)
    except:
        self.conn = DriverRemoteConnection(f'wss://{neptune_endpt}:8182/gremlin','g')
        self.g = traversal().withRemote(self.conn)
```

Here `self.conn` was initialized as:

```
self.conn = DriverRemoteConnection(f'wss://{neptune_endpt}:8182/gremlin','g')
```

Is there any way to get around this connection error?

Thanks

**Update**: Added the error message below:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/rundev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py
", line 58, in toList
    return list(iter(self))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/rundev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py
", line 48, in __next__
    self.traversal_strategies.apply_strategies(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/rundev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py
", line 573, in apply_strategies
    traversal_strategy.apply(traversal)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/rundev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/remote_connec
tion.py", line 149, in apply
    remote_traversal = self.remote_connection.submit(traversal.bytecode)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/rundev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/driver_remote
_connection.py", line 56, in submit
    results = result_set.all().result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/rundev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/resultset.py"
, line 90, in cb
    f.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/rundev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py
", line 83, in _receive
    status_code = self._protocol.data_received(data, self._results)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/rundev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py",
 line 81, in data_received
    'message': 'Server disconnected - please try to reconnect', 'attributes': {}})
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: Server disconnected - please try to reconnect
```

Comment: How long does it take before you see the connection error? And is IAM Auth enabled in your cluster?

Comment: Getting same error.  Is there any work around ?

Comment: @vissu The only work-around that worked for me was to recreate  the `remoteConn` object each time my API need to manipulate/query the Neptune DB, and then call `close()` on the `remoteConn` object once done. This increases the latency but is the only thing that worked for me. (The reason to call `close()` is that otherwise your code will start throwing the `Too many open files` error).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that this is the best way to solve this, but I'm also using gremlin-python and Neptune and I've had the same issue. I worked around it by implementing a Transport that you can provide to DriverRemoteConnection.

```py
DriverRemoteConnection(
    url=endpoint,
    traversal_source=self._traversal_source,
    transport_factory=Transport
)
```

gremlin-python returns connections to the pool on exception and the exception returned when a connection is closed is GremlinServerError which is also raised for other errors.

[gremlin_python/driver/connection.py#L69](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/python/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py#L69) -
[gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py#L80](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/python/gremlin_python/driver/protocol.py#L80)

The custom transport is the same as gremlin-python's TornadoTransport but the read and write methods are extended to:

- Reopen closed connections, if the web socket client is closed
- Raise a StreamClosedError, if the web socket client returns None from read_message

Dead connections that are added back to the pool are able to be reopended and then, you can then handle the StreamClosedError to apply some retry logic. I did it by overriding the submit and submitAsync methods in DriverRemoteConnection, but you could catch and retry anywhere.

```py
class Transport(AbstractBaseTransport):
    def __init__(self):
        self._ws = None
        self._loop = ioloop.IOLoop(make_current=False)
        self._url = None

        # Because the transport will try to reopen the underlying ws connection
        # track if the closed() method has been called to prevent the transport
        # from reopening.
        self._explicit_closed = True

    @property
    def closed(self):
        return not self._ws.protocol

    def connect(self, url, headers=None):
        self._explicit_closed = False

        # Set the endpoint URL
        self._url = httpclient.HTTPRequest(url, headers=headers) if headers else url

        # Open the connection
        self._connect()

    def write(self, message):
        # Before writing, try to ensure that the connection is open.
        if self.closed:
            self._connect()

        self._loop.run_sync(lambda: self._ws.write_message(message, binary=True))

    def read(self):
        result = self._loop.run_sync(self._ws.read_message)

        # If the read call returns None, the stream has closed.
        if result is None:
            self._ws.close()  # Ensure we close the stream
            raise StreamClosedError()

        return result

    def close(self):
        self._ws.close()
        self._loop.close()
        self._explicit_closed = True

    def _connect(self):
        # If close() was called explicitly on the transport, don't allow
        # subsequent calls to write() to reopen the connection.
        if self._explicit_closed:
            raise TransportClosedError(
                "Transport has been closed and can not be reopened."
            )

        # Check if the ws is closed, if it is not, close it.
        if self._ws and not self.closed:
            self._ws.close()

        # Open the ws connection
        self._ws = self._loop.run_sync(
            lambda: websocket.websocket_connect(url=self._url)
        )


class TransportClosedError(Exception):
    pass
```

This will work in with gremlin-pythons connection pooling as well.

If you don't need pooling, an alternate approach is to set the pool size to 1 and implement some form of keep-alive like is discussed here. [TINKERPOP-2352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2352)

It looks like the web socket ping/keep-alive in gremlin-python is not implemented yet [TINKERPOP-1886](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1886).

Comment: `self._explicit_closed = True` in `__init__`
This never gets set to False so connection never succeeds.
is `self._forced_closed = False` supposed to be `self._explicit_closed = False` in `connect`?

Comment: Thanks @korri123 this is fixed now :)